# Add some text and an input box to a table cell through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, appendchild

I'm trying to add a row with two columns to a pre-existing table in HTML. So far I have successfully done this. However, I would like to have both text and an input box in each cell. So far, this is the closest I've come:

```
newinputbox = document.createElement("input");
newinputbox.setAttribute("type", "text");

table = document.getElementById("input_table");
row = table.insertRow(3);
cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
thetext = document.createTextNode("Text:");
cell1.appendChild(thetext, newinputbox);
```

Unfortunately, this just returns the text. If I get rid of the `thetext` in the `cell1.appendChild(thetext, newinputbox)` statement, then it only returns the input box.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: why don't you use `cell1.innerText="Text:"` ? (keeping `appendChild` for the input)

Comment: [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) takes only one argument and appends only one node at a time.

Comment: @jonatjano Yeah, that works. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that `appendChild()` can receive an indefinite number of arguments to append. It expects only one; any subsequent ones are ignored.

Simpler solution:

```
cell1.appendChild(newinputbox);
cell1.innerHTML += 'Text:';
```

Comment: I think here `innerText` would be better. Plus if you keep an assign to `innerHTML` after `appendChild` it will remove the child

Comment: Not if you use `+=` it won't. In fact, using `innerText`, with `=` or `+=`, *will* remove the other child elements.

Comment: didn't see it ^^

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. I'd come to almost exactly that before, but I'd just done innerHTML = 'Text' instead of +=. I didn't think that appendChild(thetext, newinputbox) would work, but it was the best thing I had. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is the simple misunderstanding of how `Node.appendChild()` works; it takes only one argument and appends only one child element on each call.

The easiest means of fixing the error, therefore, is to simply call `Node.appendChild()` a second time:

```js
let newinputbox = document.createElement("input");
newinputbox.setAttribute("type", "text");

let table = document.getElementById("input_table"),
  row = table.insertRow(0),
  cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
  cell2 = row.insertCell(1),
  thetext = document.createTextNode("Text:");

// append the first of the new child elements:
cell1.appendChild(thetext);

// append the second of the new child elements:
cell1.appendChild(newinputbox);
```

```html
<table id="input_table">
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8rmbc1vq/).

Alternatively you could create a simple helper function that takes multiple arguments and appends each of those nodes:

```js
// defining a simple named function that takes two arguments,
// parent: the node to which the child nodes are to be appended,
// and an indefinite number (zero or more) of other arguments
// which are the child nodes to be appended.
// This uses a spread operator to destructure the arguments
// following 'parent' to be an array-like iterable object:
function appendMultiple(parent, ...progeny) {

  // here we use forEach to iterate over the contents of the
  // progeny variable:
  progeny.forEach(

    // 'child' refers to the current 'child' node of the
    // 'array' of child nodes:
    (child) => parent.appendChild(child)
  );
}

let newinputbox = document.createElement("input");
newinputbox.setAttribute("type", "text");

let table = document.getElementById("input_table"),
  row = table.insertRow(0),
  cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
  cell2 = row.insertCell(1),
  thetext = document.createTextNode("Text:");
appendMultiple(cell1, thetext, newinputbox);
```

```html
<table id="input_table">
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8rmbc1vq/2/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).